# Shopify iOS SDK - issue converting BuyProductVariant to BuyProduct

Tags: ios, objective-c, shopify

I am having an issue converting a BuyProductVariant to BuyProduct, as from BuyCart i am getting the array of all the Variants which are added in that cart with the following code

```
NSArray *arr = cart.lineItems;
```

Now as per my understanding, this array contains all the Variants which are added in the Cart.

After that I am getting those object in BuyProductVariant

```
for (int j=0; j<arr.count; j++) {
     BUYProductVariant *variant = arr[j];
     //As the product is defined in BuyProductVariant class
     BUYProduct *product = variant.product;
     //But when the above line executes the app crashes, below is the description
}
```

> exception: -[__NSDictionaryM product]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd3286d3c50

Now, in the above code, where am i doing the wrong, any help would be very helpful to me.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry for inconvenience. I think you might completed an app using Shopify. I need your help a lot. Please look into this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904455/how-to-print-the-cart-items-remove-cart-items-in-shopify-ios-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the BUYCart.lineItems array does not contain BUYProductVariant object. It contains BUYCartLineItem objects. You can retrieve your BUYProductVariant from it.

```
for (BUYCartLineItem* line in cart.lineItems) {

    BUYProductVariant* productVariant = line.variant;
}
```