# How to print the cart items,remove cart items in shopify ios sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, shopify

Hi I'm using Shopify ios sdk for my e-commerce app.I created login,signup and even list out the products in table view.I need to view products in my cart.So far I found only `buyCart.clear;` in shopify which clears all the cart item. I tried to print cart items by `BUYProductVariant *variant = cartArray[i];` but it produces error.I struck here and don't know how to proceed further. Can any one help me to solve this and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you get `BUYProduct` from `BUYCart`

```
BUYCart *cartvalue = yourCart;

NSMutableArray *arrCartProducts = [NSMutableArray new];

arrCartProducts = [[cartvalue lineItems]mutableCopy];

// I am assuming you have at least one product in your cart

if (arrCartProducts.count !=0 ) {
    BUYCartLineItem *cartLintItemvalue=[arrCartProducts objectAtIndex:0] ;
    BUYProductVariant *variantsValue=[cartLintItemvalue variant];
    BUYProduct *product= [variantsValue product];
}
```

and this is how you remove `BUYProductVariant` from `BUYCart`

```
BUYCartLineItem *cartLintItemvalue=[arrCartProducts objectAtIndex:0];
BUYProductVariant *variantsValue=[cartLintItemvalue variant];
[cartvalue removeVariant:variantsValue];
```

Comment: I try with this code. How can I remove particular product from cart?

Comment: I added a product to cart in web. Will it update in my app or do I have to do this?

Comment: I don't think it will update in your app, you need to add it through app only, as i have to manage only in app so I don't go for synchronization with Website

Comment: Okay thank you very much. One last thing, How to keep the user logged in in the app or check if the user is logged in. If you want means I can ask a seperate question.

Comment: Well, that's a totally separate question nothing linked with Shopify, so it will be better if you post another question ;)

Comment: I posted the question please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905886/how-to-keep-the-user-logged-in-or-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in-or-not-in-shopi

Comment: @Rajat plz help me with this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852426/how-can-i-add-item-in-shopify-cart-and-how-can-i-know