# How to keep the user logged in or check if the user is logged in or not in Shopify?

Tags: ios, objective-c, shopify

Hi I used the following code to login a user in Shopify.

```
NSArray *items = @[[BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithEmail:email], [BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithPassword:password]];
        BUYAccountCredentials *credentials = [BUYAccountCredentials credentialsWithItems:items];

        [self.client loginCustomerWithCredentials:credentials callback:^(BUYCustomer * customer, BUYCustomerToken * token, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (customer && !error) {

                NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [prefs setObject:token.accessToken forKey:@"CustomerToken"];


                [prefs setInteger:[token.customerID integerValue] forKey:@"CustomerId"];
                [prefs synchronize];



                NSLog(@"Success fully loged in token %@ %@",token.accessToken,token.customerID);
                UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
                [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            }else{
                [self showEror:@"LogIn Failed" message:@"Please provide valid Details"];
            }
        }];
```

Every time I have to login and proceed further. I stored token and customerId in local. How can I make sure that user automatically log in when app opens unless they doesn't logout. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are storing `CustomerToken` in your `NSUserDefault`, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` check the value of `CustomerToken` if there is any value in it navigate the user to your Home Screen if there is not any value in it then navigate the user to your Login Screen.

Also, make sure while logging out, you will clear the value from `NSUserDefault`

Comment: NSLog(@"Customeer token %@",self.client.customerToken.accessToken); it shows null. Then how can I able to add a product to customer's cart? I didn't log out while closing the app.

Comment: After initialising BUYClient. But once I go and login means it shows correct token.

Comment: Yes delete the app and login, then it will store value

Comment: The callback will include a customer and a token. Save the token if you want to persist authenticated sessions across application launches. Remember to keep it private, and save it only in the user's keychain or similar secure location. These lines are from documentation. How can I use token and customer id for authenticated sessions?

Comment: Well, for that I will suggest you go through the docs, as they clearly mentioned that you can store tokens and use those for further use, also as suggested in doc use keychain to store the value not NSUserDefault

Comment: Can you please look into this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910777/shopify-sync-cart-with-customer